# Mongodb Nested document update?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5705f793e4b0acd6e2456804a"
    },
    "Categories": [
        {
            "mainmodels": [
                {
                    "submodels": [
                        {
                            "price": "2000",
                            "submodelname": "lumia021",
                            "Remainingphones": "0",
                            "Bookedphones": "0",
                            "Numofphones": "10"
                        }

                    ],
                    "Status": "Active",
                    "modelname": "lumia",
                    "fromdate": "2016-04-01T16:39:12.051Z",
                    "todate": "2016-04-31T19:19:44.051Z"
                }
            ],
            "brand": "nokia"
        }
    ],
    "rank": "1",
    "name": "kalasipalaya"
}
```

Above I have given my data which is stored in the database (mongodb). Here I want to update Remainingphones and Bookedphones. Here 
I am trying to update but it's not updating because I have created nested document help me out get it done

Given code I have written in Angular front end server

```
credentials = 
{
    "Categories.mainmodels.submodels.Bookedphones": '1',
    "Categories.mainmodels.submodels.Remainingphones":'9'
}
$http.put('http://localhost:3000/phones/' + '5705f793e4b0acd6e2456804a', credentials).success(function(data, status, headers, config, response) {
});
```

When I run this it hits backend server route

```
app.route('/phones/:findId')
                .get(phones.read)
                .put(phones.update)
                .delete(phones.delete);
app.param('findId', phones.phomesByID );
```

for find id I am using this

```
exports.phomesByID = function(req, res, next, id) {

        Phones.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, phones) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                if (! phones) return next(new Error('Failed to load Phones ' + id));
                req.phones = phones ;
                next();
        });
};
```

for updating I have used

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
console.log(req.phones);
        var phones = req.phones ;

        phones = _.extend(phones , req.body);
        console.log(phones);
        phones.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                        return res.status(400).send({
                                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                        });
                } else {
                        res.jsonp(phones);
                }
        });
};
```

i have made model like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var submodelSchema = {
   submodelname: {type:String, required: false},
   price: {type:String, required: false},
   Remainingphones: {type:String, required: false},
   Bookedphones: {type:String, required: false},
   Numofphones: {type:String, required: false}
 };

submodelSchema  = 'new Schema('+ submodeleSchema +',{_id:true})';

var typeSchema = {
   vtype: {type:String, required: false},
   mainservices: {
   Status: {type:String, required: false},
   modelname : {type:String, required: false},
   fromdate: {type:String, required: false},
   todate: {type:String, required: false}
   },
   submodels: [submodelSchema], default:[]
};
typeSchema  = 'new Schema('+typeSchema +',{_id:true})';

var PhoneSchema = new Schema({
        rank: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
                trim: true
        },
        name: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
                trim: true
        },
   Categories: [typeSchema], default:[]


});
 mongoose.model('Phone', PhoneSchema);
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no i am not getting error . i am getting 200 response but when i check in database it's not updating

Answer (score 0):

From your code I see that you do not embed directly the phones but you make an array of embedded documents, in order for mongo to understand what you are trying to do, your update query should be something in this manner:

```
var credentials = {
    "Categories[0].mainmodels[0].submodels.Bookedphones": '1',
    "Categories[0].mainmodels[0].submodels.Remainingphones":'9'
};
```

This schema design seems a bit odd, I suggest you to revise it, it is not very intuitive.